maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'} doesn't resolve in Gradle Kotlin DSL
I'm trying to use the dependency
implementation("com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0")

in Android Studio, in a Java project using Gradle with Kotlin DSL, but
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

gives an error: see image of code.
Can some one who knows this problem resolve please?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In Kotlin DSL you can simply use:
maven("https://jitpack.io")


The full syntax would permit to add further options beside the url,alike RepositoryContentDescriptor content {}, for mapping package-names:
maven {
    url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
}

Basically, this is a: org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.ArtifactRepository
